# How to maintain folder structure for html and other resources for golang webapp?

Tags: html, go, directory

In my web application, I am maintaining the following folder structure for the web resources,

```
/Users/Dinesh/go/src/github.com/dineshappavoo/test-proj/
                                                      main.go
                                                      README.md
                                                      app/
                                                          about.html
                                                          home.html
                                                          server.go
                                                          resources/
                                                                   css/
                                                                   js/
                                                                   fonts/
                                                      mypack/
                                                            abc/
```

In server.go under app folder I am starting the web server and rendering the html etc. In main.go [under top level folder] I am trying to call the server.go function. I am doing this because I can maintain the go dependencies and easily build the project.

Here is my main.go content,

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/dineshappavoo/test-proj/app"
)

func main() {
    app.Main()
}
```

and server.go code snippet is here,

```
package app

import (
    "html/template"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
    ....
    ....
)


//Home page handler
func homeHandler(
    w http.ResponseWriter,
    r *http.Request,
) {
    renderTemplate(w, "home", nil)
}

//About page handler
func aboutHandler(
    w http.ResponseWriter,
    r *http.Request,
) {

    renderTemplate(w, "about", nil)
}

var templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("about.html", "home.html"))

func renderTemplate(
    w http.ResponseWriter,
    tmpl string,
    p interface{},
) {
    //If you use variables other than the struct u r passing as p, then "multiple response.WriteHeader calls" error may occur. Make sure you pass
    //all variables in the struct even they are in the header.html embedded
    if err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, tmpl+".html", p); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}

//URL validation for basic web services
var validPath = regexp.MustCompile("^/$|/(home|about)/(|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$")

func validate(
    fn func(
        http.ResponseWriter,
        *http.Request,
    )) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(
        w http.ResponseWriter,
        r *http.Request,
    ) {
        //log.Printf("Request URL Path %s ", r.URL.Path)
        m := validPath.FindStringSubmatch(r.URL.Path)
        if m == nil {
            http.NotFound(w, r)
            return
        }
        fn(w, r)
    }
}

//Main method to install
func Main() {
    log.Printf("TEST APP SERVER STARTED")

    http.HandleFunc("/", validate(homeHandler))
    http.HandleFunc("/home/", validate(homeHandler))
    http.HandleFunc("/about/", validate(aboutHandler))

    http.Handle("/resources/", http.StripPrefix("/resources/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("resources"))))
    //http.Handle("/templ/", http.StripPrefix("/templ/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("templ"))))
    if *addr {
        l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:0")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        err = ioutil.WriteFile("final-port.txt", []byte(l.Addr().String()), 0644)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        s := &http.Server{}
        s.Serve(l)
        return
    }

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

When I start the server.go directly it works [by making Main() in server.go as main() and go run server.go]. But when I use the above structure it fails.

**Error:**

```
panic: open about.html: no such file or directory

goroutine 1 [running]:
html/template.Must(0x0, 0x81a568, 0x11980f20, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/html/template/template.go:304 +0x40
github.com/dineshappavoo/test-proj/app.init()
    /Users/Dinesh/go/src/github.com/dineshappavoo/test-proj/app/server.go:625 +0x1ec
main.init()
    /Users/Dinesh/go/src/github.com/dineshappavoo/test-proj/main.go:9 +0x39
```

**EDIT-I**
I gave the absolute path for html templates. It worked. But css is not loading. I changed the following line.

```
http.Handle("/resources/", http.StripPrefix("/resources/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/app/"))))
```

I am new to go language. Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: You are calling `template.Must` - which panics on an error - and the app is generating an error because it cannot find `about.html`. If you're calling `go run` then your application is likely run from temporary directory. You should either call `go build` or instead provide an absolute path to your template files (better). Try to avoid using `go run` outside of a small, single-file programs.

Comment: @elithrar - I am building the app using go build ./... and go install ./... under test-proj folder. And running the project by ./test-proj. Should I change this approach?

Comment: Your question says you are using `go run server.go`? Is that not the case?

Comment: I used just to make sure it is working. It works when I use go run server.go. But I am getting error when I use the top level binary ./test-proj

Comment: You were right. I used the absolute path of the html files. It worked. But I am not sure why it failed in the previously. Thanks elithrar. I will add that answer.

Comment: It failed because (as per my first comment) `go run` builds and runs the program in a temporary directory. That temporary directory doesn't contain your template files, but your program was referring to `about.html` as if it did contain them. It is nearly always better to use absolute paths or provide an option to do so via a flag or environmental variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99002/discussion-between-dinesh-appavoo-and-elithrar).

Comment: css is not loading :(.  Could someone help me with that? [The same folder structure as you can see in the question]